# Accessing Expression.DebugView from code

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm creating an expression tree manually like this

```
var innerAddition = Expression.Add(Expression.Constant(5), Expression.Constant(9));
var mult = Expression.Multiply(innerAddition, Expression.Constant(2));
var top = Expression.Add(Expression.Constant(3), mult);
```

When I look at DebugView in debug mode, I see 3 + (5 + 9) * 2, which is what I would like to output from my program. I understand this is using the expression tree visualizer. Is there a way to use this from my code?
Thanks!

Comment: I've written a [library which can generate a string from an expression tree in multiple formats](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString), among them a better C#-style alternative to `DebugView`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classes that implement the debug view features are intentionally `internal` so that you cannot access them without reflection.  Although this seems unfair, the purpose of debugging is debugging and it is not intended as a supported API and therefore could change at any time, perhaps to improve debugging!  Using the supported public APIs will ensure compatibility with future versions.

Here is another StackOverflow question using the public APIs:

- [Print out Linq Expression Tree Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697463/print-out-linq-expression-tree-hierarchy)

Answer (score 14):

Here is a simple extension method to get the internal property's value using reflection.

```
public static string GetDebugView(this Expression exp)
{
    if (exp == null)
        return null;

    var propertyInfo = typeof(Expression).GetProperty("DebugView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(exp) as string;
}
```

Comment: this is real the solution

Answer (score 1):

While the classes are internal, the source code is public :-)

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/DebugViewWriter.cs,05c213f459ccd9cb

Obviously you have to fix up a few things but its not too difficult to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/ExpressionStringBuilder.cs gives the mouse-over text you see for an expression in Visual Studio when debugging.

Depending on your needs either that or DebugViewWriter.cs as Andrew Jackson mentioned should cover things.